# Qooxdoo - command shortcut not translating

Tags: internationalization, qooxdoo

If I run following code in the playground:

```
var button1 = new qx.ui.form.Button("First Button", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");
var doc = this.getRoot();
doc.add(button1, { left : 100, top  : 50 });
button1.addListener("execute", function(e) { alert("Hello World!"); });
button1.setToolTipText(new qx.ui.core.Command("Control+D").toString());
qx.locale.Manager.getInstance().setLocale("en");
```

The Button-Tooltip shows Ctrl+D.

If I change the locale to "de" the tooltip still shows Ctrl+D. On the second run it shows Strg+D, the correct string.

How can I make it to show the correct string on the first run?

An even better example which shows my problem is this:

```
var doc = this.getRoot();
var button1 = new qx.ui.form.Button("Deutsch", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");
doc.add(button1, { left : 100, top  : 50 });
button1.addListener("execute", function(e) { qx.locale.Manager.getInstance().setLocale("de"); });
button1.setToolTipText(new qx.ui.core.Command("Control+D").toString());

var button2 = new qx.ui.form.Button("English", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");
doc.add(button2, { left : 200, top  : 50 });
button2.addListener("execute", function(e) { qx.locale.Manager.getInstance().setLocale("en"); });
button2.setToolTipText(new qx.ui.core.Command("Control+E").toString());
```

Have a look at the tooltips.

Is this a bug or am I not setting the locales the correct way?

/Kind regards

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with both of your snippets is that of evalutation and order. For one thing, `qx.ui.core.Command("Control+D").toString()` just returns a plain string, given the current locale. After that, the value is "fixed" and is not changed automatically anymore. In your first snippet, you **first** set the tooltip, and **then** change the locale. That means, the tooltip is set according to whatever locale is in effect before switching to "en". If you then re-run the snippet (I presume you are using the Playground), setting the tooltip is executed under the new locale and the tooltip shows the English version.

In the second snippet, changing the locale in the "execute" listener has no effect on the tooltip, as its value is already "hard-wired" using whatever locale was in effect at the time the code is evaluated (and **not** when one of the buttons is pressed!). Of course, if you press one of the buttons and then re-run the code in Playground, the new locale is then being picked up and displayed in the tooltips.

One way to work around this is to set the tooltip in the "execute" listener. [See this Playground example.](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.3/playground/index.html#%7B%22code%22%3a%20%22var%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot%28%29%253B%250Avar%2520button1%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button%28%2522Deutsch%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522%29%253B%250Adoc.add%28button1%252C%2520%257B%2520left%2520%253A%2520100%252C%2520top%2520%2520%253A%252050%2520%257D%29%253B%250Abutton1.addListener%28%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function%28e%29%2520%257B%2520%250A%2520%2520qx.locale.Manager.getInstance%28%29.setLocale%28%2522de%2522%29%253B%250A%2520%2520button1.setToolTipText%28new%2520qx.ui.core.Command%28%2522Control%252BD%2522%29.toString%28%29%29%253B%250A%257D%29%253B%250A%250Avar%2520button2%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button%28%2522English%2522%252C%2520%2522icon%252F22%252Fapps%252Finternet-web-browser.png%2522%29%253B%250Adoc.add%28button2%252C%2520%257B%2520left%2520%253A%2520200%252C%2520top%2520%2520%253A%252050%2520%257D%29%253B%250Abutton2.addListener%28%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function%28e%29%2520%257B%2520%250A%2520%2520qx.locale.Manager.getInstance%28%29.setLocale%28%2522en%2522%29%253B%250A%2520%2520button2.setToolTipText%28new%2520qx.ui.core.Command%28%2522Control%252BE%2522%29.toString%28%29%29%253B%250A%257D%29%253B%22%7D)
(It's not very sensible, but I think you can work from this onward).

Comment: aaahhh .. thx a lot, of course the string is fixed and not reevaluated every time, sometimes it is the easy solution